# Category page 2 noindex?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I can't seem to find out why my category page #2 has a "NOINDEX,FOLLOW"

Is there a setting for that so I can edit it all my category pages to "INDEX,FOLLOW" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a setting for it in System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> HTML Head

Comment: That's default but then page 2 of a category isn't the same setting. I get a different tag on the deeper category results pages.